# R package to guess x y coordinates from static image?

Tags: r, image, ocr

I know it's a long shot. Is there any R package to take an image and guess at the x y coordinates, then generate a CSV or TSV file. Or maybe some routine or function? Would make life a lot easier. I have to recreate old charts like this.

At the moment I'm forced to manually choose x and y coordinates.

[image]

Comment: Not an R solution, but this might be useful for you: https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/ it can output the data as CSV and you can use R from there.

Comment: google `"digitize pixel plot extract data"`, 1. try many, 2. find the right one

Comment: If you have to do less than 100 charts i would not even think of going programming/automation/algorithm style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the R package "[digitize](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/digitize/index.html)", but I can't vouch for how good it is.

Comment: rather a comment IMO

Comment: Seems to me that's exactly the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @iod I gave you an upvote anyways to cancel out one of the downvotes, as you said it answers the question I posed. Is obviously in good faith. Every so often something I do on here gets downvoted for no apparent reason to me. I wouldn't worry about it, and I don't.

Comment: @iod I did not downvote! The question is considered off topic and i feel like its not an answer according to SO guidance.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 1 graph, I would use Graph Grabber

https://www.quintessa.org/software/downloads-and-demos/graph-grabber-2.0.2

Define the X & Y min/max, then you trace the line, it will then provide an csv containing all the x & y values.